# Error: Undefined function or variable "B" when trying to find zeros of a function

Tags: matlab

I'm having a little trouble evaluating `B` in the function `bidfn`. More specifically, I have been unable to find the zeroes of `C` from the nested function `ptesta`.

Just for some context, `Dmr` is the numerical solution to a first-order differential equation at the 101 points in `A`. `srfna` and `stfna` are my attempts to find `sr` and `st` in `x=K(sr)` and `B=RR(st)` respectively. (As of yet, I have found no way of finding the inverses of `K` and `RR` since they can only be solved for numerically.)

My problem is that `C` is a function of `st` and `stfna` takes `B` as its input. So, anytime I try to evaluate `bidfn` for a given `x` I get the following error:

```
Undefined function or variable "B".

     Error in bidfn/stfna (line 72)
     if B<=RR(1)

     Error in bidfn (line 15)
     st=stfna;
```

I know the issue is that I want to solve for `B` while `B` is also an input in `stfna`. What I’m not sure of is how to get around this issue. I run into the same problem when I use `fsolve` instead of `fzero`. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

My code is as follows:

```
function B=bidfn(x)

%%% DEFINITIONS

K=Dmr;          % this is the solution to the ODE dmr/ds
A=0:0.01:1;     % this is the set of points K is solved at
for i=1:101     
 RR=A+K;        % this function combines the two
end 

%%% FUNCTION CALLS

fun=@ptesta;
sr=srfna;
st=stfna;

%%% B FUNCTION

if x<0.5
    B=0;

elseif x==0.5
    B=0.5;

elseif x>=0.5+K(101)
    B=x+0.5;

else
    x0=[0,1];
    B=fzero(fun,x0);
end


%%% NESTED FUNCTIONS

    %%% Nested function 1

    function C=ptesta

        for y=1:101
            z1=integral(A(y)+x,0,sr(y));
            z2=integral(RR(y),st(y),sr(y));
            C=(z1-z2)-B*st(y);
        end
    end 


    %%% Nested function 2

    function sr=srfna

        if x<=K(1)
            sr=0;

        elseif x>=K(101)
            sr=1;

        else
            for q=2:100
                if x>=K(q-1) && x<K(q)
                    sr=A(q-1);
                end
            end
        end
    end 


    %%% Nested function 3

    function st=stfna  

        if B<=RR(1)  
            st=0;

        elseif B>=RR(101)
            st=1;

        else
            for v=2:100
                if B>=RR(v-1) && B<RR(v)
                    st=A(v-1);
                end
            end
        end
    end


%%% END OF NESTED FUNCTIONS

end
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. However, when I follow the flow of your code, even I reach the same conclusion. `B` is undefined. You call `srfna` which does not have any mention of `B`. Suddenly, first line in `stfna` is `if B<=RR(1)`.

Comment: Could I ask in which way the question is unclear so that I may make it clearer?

I understand what the error is and why it is there. My issue is that `fun` is a function of both `B` and `st` and `st` itself is a function of  `B` (this is not a mistake, this is simply the way the model I am studying operates). This means that I cannot evaluate `B=fzero(fun,x0)` without first specifying `B`, since without  `B`,  `st` cannot be evaluated.

I apologise for the delay in replying, something came up.

Comment: What is the model supposed to return if B is undefined? Normally there would be some sort of starting/default value - e.g. B = 0. This isn't a matter of code, so much as that you can't ask it to compute something that doesn't exist.  It doesn't matter if it's your function or `x+1`, if `x` is undefined then `x+1` is undefined. Incidentally, there's an issue with your loop inside that function, too, in that you're overwriting `st` multiple times and will only get the final value.

Comment: The problem is that in the row `st=stfna;` you call `stfna` which starts with `if B<=RR(1) , st=0;`. The problem is: What `B` at this point? Since you have not defined `B`. How can you say if it is smaller or larger than `RR`. How can you say that `B` is not even instance of a class `Car`? You need to set an initial value to `B`

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The model is supposed to solve for a `B` that makes `C=0`. If I can put it differently, in the current code, `stfna` must be solved before `B=fzero(fun,x0)`. This is where my problem is coming from since `B` must be defined for `stfna` to be defined, but by defining `B` I cannot adequately solve the `B` that ensures `C=0`. What I would like to know is; is there a way to rewrite my code such that `stfna` and `B=fzero(fun,x0)` can be solved for `B` simultaneously? (i.e., should I solve for all values of `B` in a certain interval and see which gets closest to `C=0`.)

Comment: Also, with regards to overwriting `st` multiple times. Could I ask how to resolve that issue?